# Extract data from text file in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell

I'm wondering if it is even possible to grab specific data from text file with format like below:

```
Adapter Number:         1
Adapter Name:           elxfc
                                Device 1
                                SCSI id:                1
                                LUN:                    0
                                Vendor:                 HP
                                Product:                Ultrium 4-SCSI
                                Firmware:               H6FW



Adapter Number:         2
Adapter Name:           elxfc
                                Device 1
                                SCSI id:                1
                                LUN:                    0
                                Vendor:                 HP
                                Product:                Ultrium 4-SCSI
                                Firmware:               H6FW


                                Changer 1
                                SCSI id:                1
                                LUN:                    1
                                Vendor:                 HP
                                Product:                MSL G3 Series
                                Firmware:               8.70
```

Form here at the end I woul like to get info about devices to get output like:

```
Ultrium 4-SCSI, 1 1 0
Ultrium 4-SCSI, 2 1 0
MSL G3 Series, 2 1 1
```

I've tried some basic string operations, but no luck. The problem is to catch second device within the same "main" Adapter Number.

Comment: For something like this you need to match multiple things and keep some state around (eg. matching adapter number to remember that when matching the details). `switch -regex` is very powerful for this type of matching.

Comment: I've got a problem to keep in this example "Adapter Number 2" to grab output this "2" for second device in this adapter.

Basically what I've got now is reading file line by line, to find strong "Adapter number" string and return number after ":" then read next lines to catch numbers from strings with: "SCSI Id" and "LUN", so I'm getting:

Device 1, 1 1 0

I will go in this way:
Read line by line,
Catch "Adapter Number" string and return number 
Catch SCSI Id and LUN string until next line with Adapter Number will show up. 
I will post result later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
switch -regex -file $inputFile {
  "Adapter Number:\s+(\d+)" { $adapterNumber = $Matches[1]; break; }
  "\s+SCSI id:\s+(\d+)" { $scsiId = $Matches[1]; break; }
  "\s+LUN:\s+(\d+)" { $lun = $Matches[1]; break; }
  "\d+Product:\s+(.+)" { 
                   $prod = $Matches[1];
                   "{0}, {1} {2} {3}" -f $prod, $adapterNumber, $scsiId, $lun;
                  }
}
```

should do it.

With the `-regex` witch the matching is done with regexes, with `-file` each line of the passed file is processed through the switch (see [online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750.aspx) for more details on PSH's `switch`). Otherwise it is just keeping the state needed for output when `Product:` is matched.

Comment: I will definitelly test this! Thanks for sharing